# Spring Boot: Configure h2 jdbc url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

The in memory database in spring boot configuration is working fine, with below code. But the url is not picking up from from *YAML* configuration. though the *h2 console* is enabled

In log the url is printing as memory db.

1. how can i change the jdbc url from memory to file.

**Log File**

> 2020-09-03 14:22:42.595 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-10.44.33.51] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Fetching JDBC Connection from DataSource

> 2020-09-03 14:22:42.595 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-10.44.33.51] DEBUG o.s.j.d.SimpleDriverDataSource - Creating new JDBC Driver Connection to [jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;MODE=Oracle;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false]

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

@Bean
@Primary
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .setName("testdb;MODE=Oracle")
            .addScript("classpath:sql/Create-table.sql")
            .build();
}
}
```

**YAML Configuration**

```
  spring:
      h2:
        console:
          enabled: true
          path: /h2
      datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:file:C:/db/test
        username: test
        password: password
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
```

Comment: It might be because your overriding the DataSource bean.

Comment: yeah, I want to run script on start up , so overrided datasource bean. At the same time i want to pass url too

Answer (score 0):

Don't define `dataSource` bean. Configure `datasource` via properties file. If you want to execute `DDL` and/or `DML` sql script when app starts you can do something like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:file:C:/db/test
    username: test
    password: password
    schema: classpath:sql/Create-table.sql
    data: classpath:sql/fill-table.sql
```

By default Spring Boot looking for files `schema.sql` and `data.sql` in the root of app's classpath (e.g. `src/main/resources/schema.sql`) but you can override this behavior in properties *`spiring.datasource.schema`* and *`spring.datasource.data`* just like in code example above.